# Django-REST Serializer: Queryset does not filter PrimaryKeyRelatedField results

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

So I have a serializer that looks like this

```
class BuildingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    masterlisting_set = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, 
                                    queryset=Masterlistings.objects.all())
```

and it works great

```
serializer = BuildingsSerializer(Buildings.objects.get(pk=1))
serializer.data
```

produces

```
OrderedDict([
    ("masterlistings_set", [
        "0a06e3d7-87b7-4526-a877-c10f54fa5bc9",
        "343643ac-681f-4597-b8f5-ff7e5be65eef",
        "449a3ad2-c76c-4cb8-bb86-1be72fafcf64",
    ])
])
```

but if I change the queryset in the serializer to

```
class BuildingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     masterlistings_set = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=[])
```

I still get the same exact result back.

```
 OrderedDict([
    ("masterlistings_set", [
        "0a06e3d7-87b7-4526-a877-c10f54fa5bc9",
        "343643ac-681f-4597-b8f5-ff7e5be65eef",
        "449a3ad2-c76c-4cb8-bb86-1be72fafcf64",
    ])
])
```

Is this supposed to be happening? Am I using querysets incorrectly?
I used [] as an easy example to show that no matter what I put in nothing changes.

Please any insight would be invaluable

It should be noted that masterlistings has a primary key relationship that points to buildings. So a masterlisting belong to a building.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As pointed out by @zymud, queryset argument in PrimaryKeyRelatedField is used for validating field input for creating new entries. 
Another solution for filtering out masterlistings_set is to use serializers.SerializerMethodField() as follows:

```
class BuildingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    masterlisting_set = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_masterlisting_set(self, obj):
        return MasterListing.objects.filter(building=obj).values_list('pk',flat=True)
```

Comment: Awesome, I'm accepting this answer because its the cleaner of the two!

Answer (score 4):

`queryset` in related field limits only acceptable values. So with `queryset=[]` you will not be able to add new values to `masterlisting_set` or create new `Buildings`.

**UPDATE. How to use queryset for filtering**

This is a little bi tricky - you need to rewrite `ManyRelatedField` and `many_init` method in your `RelatedField`.

```
# re-define ManyRelatedField `to_representation` method to filter values
# based on queryset
class FilteredManyRelatedField(serializers.ManyRelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, iterable):
        iterable = self.child_relation.queryset.filter(
            pk__in=[value.pk for value in iterable])
        return super(FilteredManyRelatedField, self).to_representation(iterable)


# use overridden FilteredManyRelatedField in `many_init`
class FilteredPrimaryKeyRelatedField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    @classmethod
    def many_init(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['child_relation'] = cls(queryset=kwargs.pop('queryset'))
        return FilteredManyRelatedField(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I see, thank you for the info. Do you know of anyway to use it to filter out the info I get from the serializer?

Comment: This is really great, thank you! I have only modified `to_representation` to use `get_queryset` instead of `queryset` to be able to filter `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` dynamically.